# Using the same text field for URL and Google Search in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, google-search

I am trying to get the URL and google search in the same Text field.. the method I am using works alright but probably there is a better way. What I am doing is to check if there is a dot in the input like www.google.com, if a dot is not found, then search it on google..

```
NSRange range = [textField.text rangeOfString:@"."];
    textField.text = (range.location != NSNotFound)          ?
                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textField.text]  :
                [@"http://www.google.com/search?q=" stringByAppendingString:textField.text ];
```

If the input has a dot, then search fails.. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

U can prevent user from entering . dot in UITextField like this by using UITextField's delegate method:

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {
   if([string isEqualToString:@"."])
   {
     return NO;
   }
   else
   {
     return YES;
   }
 }
```

Comment: That won't work if you paste in a bunch of text at once with one or more periods in it.